# Ajax get запрос

Tags: ajax, php

Делаю систему добавления друзей. На данном этапе все работает, но хотелось бы реализовать все средствами ajax, чтобы запрос передавался и обрабатывался без перезагрузки страницы.

Отправка параметров:

```
<a href='actions.php?action=send&user=$user_id' id='send' class='box'>Send friend request</a>
```

Скрипт добавления actions.php:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$my_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user'];

    if ($action == 'send') {
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO friends (friend_one,friend_two) VALUES ('$my_id','$user_id')");
        header('Refresh: 0; http://localhost/lc/messages?id='.$user_id);
    }
```

Помогите составить ajax запрос

Answer (score 1):

Глядеть примеры тут https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Реализовал вот таким образом, теперь другой вопрос как обновить блок div в котором находится кнопка добавить, ведь теперь там должно быть написано "запрос отправлен" 

$("#send").click(function() {
var user=<?php echo "$MY_FRIEND_ID";?>; 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'actions.php?action=send&user='+user,
  success: function(data) {
    if(data == 'good'){
        $("#user-page").html(data).fadeIn('fast');
    }else{
    $("#user-page").html(data).fadeIn('fast');
    }

  }});
});

Comment: if(data == 'good'){ $("#user-page").html(data).fadeIn('fast');
$('#send').html('Запрос отправлен!');
$(this).attr('id','blabla');
 }else{ $("#user-page").html(data).fadeIn('fast'); }